# Generating a link to the Sign-In in Azure B2C page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, dynamics-365

I use standard user flows and custom pages for Forgotten Password and Sign-Up. On these pages, I need to add a link to the Sign-In page. How to add the  tag itself is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/755343/azure-ad-b2c-signupsignin-combined-flow-link-from.html).

At the moment, I do not understand how to generate the link itself correctly.
Out from the box on the Sign-In page, links for Forgotten Password and Sign-Up are generated using the getRedirectLink function, but I can’t generate a link for Sign-in using it.
As an alternative, it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670125/how-to-restart-azure-ad-b2c-userjourney-when-user-cancels-signup?newreg=3e022de38ec44393bddc56169443434e) to use history.back(), but unfortunately this is not covered all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If we hard code the link (sign-in flow link) that won't work properly. A workaround is, place a link that points to your application itself.

Eg: Say "https://something.com", is your application URL and it is a page requires authentication. When you place link to this URL, MSAL will redirect automatically to sign in page.

Answer (score -1):

The `getRedirectLink` cannot be used to generate a link to the Sign-in user flow. You can it as a hard link though.

Comment: so how can you generate a link to the sign in page, that's the question isn't it ?